# QML: disable lazy-loading of tabs in TabView (or open all of them programatically)

Tags: qml, lazy-loading, tabview

I have a `TabView` with a number of `Tab`s. Some components inside tabs define `Component.onCompleted` to set up data structures (those are interfaced from c++ and must be instantiated in QML). As `Tab`s are lazy-loaded, `onCompleted` callbacks are not called until the respective tab is opened by the user.

Is there a way to make all tabs load at startup? I am currently using `Component.onCompleted{ currentIndex=1; }` in the `TabView` to open the second tab but I'd like to cycle-open all of them, without user interaction, when the whole interface is created. I tried looping with `currentIndex` over all avilable tab indices in `onCompleted` but that did not have any effect.

Comment: You could use the `TabBar` and have all the tabs instantiated but invisible, except the one that matches the correct index of the TabBar (see [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbar.html) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Tab` inherits from `Loader`, you can set its [`active` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#active-prop) to `true`.